# Delete all files in one directory with Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I've got one problem when I want to delete all files in one directory with Codeigniter..

I've been watching and trying from any tutorials, and just having one problem.. It always can't delete any files.

here's my script :

@view

```
<a href="<?php echo base_url()?>sia/delete_allfile" title="Delete All File" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure you want delete all files?')">Delete All File</a>
```

@controller

```
public function delete_allfile()
{
    $files = glob($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'upload/perizinan/*'); // get all file names
    if(is_dir($path))
    {
        $this->session->set_flashdata('message',
        '
            Wrong directory !
        ');
        redirect('sia/perizinan');
    }else
    {
        foreach($files as $file)
        { // iterate files
            if(is_file($file))
            unlink($file); // delete file
        }
        redirect('sia/perizinan');
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you get any error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using Codeigniter's file helper for deleting files. It does exactly what you're trying to do. Of course it won't work if the permissions are wrong on the folder (It requires the permission: rwxrwxrwx (0777)), but it makes for a bit cleaner and easier to debug code.
In the controller's constructor add:

```
$this->load->helper('file');
```

And replace:

```
foreach($files as $file)
    { // iterate files
        if(is_file($file))
        unlink($file); // delete file
    }
```

with

```
delete_files('./path/to/directory/');
```

Or if you want to include subfolders recursvively

```
delete_files('./path/to/directory/', TRUE);
```

This deletes ALL files in the folder/subfolders so if you want more control you're better off doing it with unlink so you can decide what to delete.

Answer (score 0):

Do you get any error message on the page or in the log file? Have you checked the folder/ files permissions? You can use the [chmod](http://php.net/manual/en/function.chmod.php) and [fileperms](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fileperms.php) functions

Comment: no error message, just redirect..

I tried to rename the folder, but the script is still like that,, and the result is like bypass the code "if(is_dir($path))"..

Comment: Not sure I understand. In any case remove the redirect and uses screen outputs, did you try printing the folder/file permission? Does the script gets to the files loop?

Answer (score 0):

It's Simple and Easy.. You can Try this.

```
    $files = glob('/home/xxx/public_html/project_name/application/*');

 foreach($files as $file){ 

 if(is_file($file))

 unlink($file);

  }
```

Answer (score 0):

It will probably work, I have used

```
$this->load->helper('directory');
$this->load->helper("file");

$dir_fiels = directory_map('resources/captcha/');
$len = sizeOf($dir_fiels);
for($i=0; $i<$len;$i++){
    unlink('resources/captcha/'.$dir_fiels[$i]);
}
```